# C making a Function Return 1 when user input is 0-9 ASCII

Tags: c

The problem I have been given to solve is as follows:
-Write a function named "is_digit" that accepts a char as input, and returns an integer value of 1 if the parameter input is an ASCII digit between 0 and 9 inclusive. Otherwise the function must return a value of 0.

-In the main function, call is_digit, and pass in an argument based upon user input. The main function must then output the result from calling is_digit.

This is what i have so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>

        char is_digit(int x)
        {
            if (x > '48' && x < '57') //The ascII range between 0-9 (i think...)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else                      
//Whatever the user input is it always runs the else
            {
                return 0;             
//Is this what the question means by "function must return a value of 0"
            }
        }

        int main()
        {
            char x;
            printf("input: ");
            scanf("%c", &x);
            is_digit(x);
        }
```

Why is my program not returning 1 if my user input is 0-9??

Updated version with comments taken into consideration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char is_digit(char x)
{
    if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
    {
        printf("1");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char x;
    printf("input: ");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    is_digit(x);
}
```

Comment: The test `if (x > '48' && x < '57')` is incorrect. Remove the single quotes, and use `>=` instead of `>` (also `<=` instead of `<`)

Comment: You're comparing an int to a character (of sorts: a two-element character; not sure how valid that is). Please use and *read* your compiler warnings.

Comment: Whoops, fixed my if statement, most appreciated! But my function still isn't returning 1.....

Comment: Updated version with comments taken into consideration. (put printf's in so i saw which statement was running when i compiled it). Still not returning 1. And there aren't any compiling errors, I think maybe just a logic error of some sort?

Comment: Are you saying that `is_digit()` is not returning a value? In fact, `is_digit()` *is* returning a value, you are just ignoring it.

Comment: The answers here are extraordinarily bad. The obviously correct test is `if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')`. Testing against the numeric values of the characters is dumb and violates fundamental programming principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is with

```
if (x > '48' && x < '57') //The ascII range between 0-9 (i think...)
```

It should be

```
if (x > 47 && x < 58) //The ascII range between 0-9 (i think...)
```

The corrected code is shown below

```
   #include <stdio.h>

            int is_digit(char x)
            {
                if (x > 47 && x < 58) //The ascII range between 0-9 (i think...)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else                      
    //Whatever the user input is it always runs the else
                {
                    return 0;             
    //Is this what the question means by "function must return a value of 0"
                }
            }

            int main()
            {
                char x;
                printf("input: ");
                scanf("%c", &x);
                printf("result is: %d",is_digit(x));
                return 0;

            }
```

A return statement in programming is a proof of what the computer did. In c and c++, returning 0 in main means your program ended correctly, without crashing but not necessarily that you code is wrong or right.

Comment: Sigh. Just write the obvious, `if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')`, then you don't have to know or care what the ASCII values are and won't risk getting them wrong.

Comment: The assignment is to print the result of is_digit. This program doesn't do that. Returning `is_digit(x)` is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Also to note use 'unsigned char x' in your main this basically means positive values 0-255

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_digit(int x)
 {
    if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
 }
```

It would be better to change your method to return an int and not char.

Remove the single quotes because you are comparing the number values of the ASCII characters (int)

Also use the '<=' and '>=' signs because the question said inclusive. '<' and '>' is exclusive.

You don't need a else block since the answer is immediately returned if it is a number.

"//Is this what the question means by "function must return a value of 0"?"

Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: int is_digit(int x)
{
    return x >= '0' && x <= '9';
}

Answer (score 1):

You could do a direct comparison:

```
int is_digit(char x)
{
    int result;
    if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the other answers testing against integer values are incompetent. But ... simply `return x >= '0' && x <= '9;` does the right thing and is probably what the instructor is hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is `char`,
try this:

```
int is_digit(int x)
```

Comment: Write a function named is_digit that accepts a "char as input", and returns an integer value of 1.

The char as input requirement is whats kinda tripping me up on this question. If it was int input it would be a piece of cake.

Comment: @F.Horn Why?  `scanf("%c", &x)` reads a char into `x` -- piece of cake. Testing it can be done with `int is_digit(int x) { return x >= '0' && x <= '9'; }` -- another piece of cake.

Comment: "Write a function named "is_digit" that accepts a char as input" is part of the questions requirements

Answer (score 0):

In short: because you're not telling it to. The final line should be:

`return is_digit(x);`

Without the `return`, the result from `is_digit()` is simply being thrown away...

Comment: Thank you so much! How foolish of me. That solve that problem.
It is returning and int, but my function always runs the else statement? Any clue as to why the if statement isn't running?

Comment: Ask the computer what value it has for x. Instead of `printf("0");` use `printf("%d", x);` It will print out the value for x instead of simply `0` - you can then find out what x is. It should be in that range, but maybe you typed a space first? Or an <Enter>? Or something else. If the output is 32 or less, then it's a space or <Enter> key. That's the problem with `scanf("%c")` - it scans the next character, regardless of what it is